# generate enum keys based on sum of enum values for permission

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an enum as

```
RoleEnum={
            None: 0,
            ViewAnalytics: 1,
            ManageTargets: 2,
            ManageBranches: 4,
            ViewActivationDetails: 8,
            ManageUsers: 16,
            ViewBilling: 32,
            ManageQuestions: 64
};
```

1. If I am getting response from DB as 7; it should return
   `["None","ViewAnalytics","ManageTargets","ManageBranches"]`
2. If I am getting response from DB as 3; it should return
   `["None","ViewAnalytics","ManageTargets"]`

and similar logic.

Then in *.ts I can get:-

```
      vm.userLevelPermission.ViewAnalytics = vm.userLevelPermission.includes('ViewAnalytics');
      vm.userLevelPermission.ManageTargets = vm.userLevelPermission.includes('ManageTargets');
```

The addition of the permission value we are getting from DB is the logic.

```
    <div class="panel-title"><h4 class="mts">User Level Permission Settings<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="vm.updateUserLevelPermission()">Save</button></h4></div>
</div>
        <tr>
            <td>Manage Targets</td>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" checked="vm.userLevelPermission.ManageTargets"></td>
            <td>View Analytics</td>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" checked="vm.userLevelPermission.ViewAnalytics"></td>
        </tr>
```

Similarly it should return the value in case of update as sum of checked boxes. If I checked both, it should return 3.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: thanks. changed a bit for the rendering in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it sounds like you are simply approaching it the wrong way.  You can just use it as a [bitmask](https://blog.rinatussenov.com/juggling-bits-in-javascript-bitmasks-128ad5f31bed), so basically you just need:

```js
const permissions = { None: 0, ViewAnalytics: 1, ManageTargets: 2, ManageBranches: 4, ViewActivationDetails: 8, ManageUsers: 16, ViewBilling: 32, ManageQuestions: 64 };
const userPermissions = 7; // for example

const userLevelPermissions = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(permissions).map(([key, value]) => {
    return [key, key === 'None' || !!(userPermissions & permissions[key])];
}));

const hasPermission = (permission) => permission === permissions.None || !!(userPermissions & permission)

console.log(hasPermission(permissions.ManageTargets))

console.log({userLevelPermissions})
```

Comment: It didn't work. Prior to this solution I tried similar approach

<code>

                    vm.userPermissions = angular.copy(response.data).permission;
                    console.log(vm.userPermissions);
                    vm.userLevelPermission = vm.userPermissions.reduce(function(map, obj) {
                        vm.userLevelPermission = vm.userLevelPermission | vm.userLevelPermissionsEnum[map] & vm.userLevelPermissionsEnum[obj];
                        console.log(vm.userLevelPermission);
                        return vm.userLevelPermission;
                    });
</code>

Comment: @RakeshPattanayak why didn't it work? Could you please add this code and the reason why it didn't work in the question?

Comment: @ShivamSingla I am getting You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

The whole project stopped working after adding the above code. Some issue is in this piece of code:-
const userLevelPermissions = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(permissions).map(([key, value]) => {
    return [key, key === 'None' || !!(userPermissions & permissions[key])];
}));

Answer (score 0):

`vm.userLevelPermission = Object.keys(vm.userLevelPermissionsEnum).map(function(key, value) {
                        vm.hasUserLevelPermission = (key === 'None' || !!(vm.userPermissions & vm.userLevelPermissionsEnum[key]));
                        return [key,value, vm.hasUserLevelPermission];
                    });`

Thanks for the earlier solution. With Object.keys() it resolved the issue.